Hume and mathematics

We have already observed that nature has established connexions among particular ideas, and that no sooner one idea occurs to our thoughts than it introduces its correlative, and carries our attention towards it, by a gentle and insensible movement. These principles of connexion or association we have reduced to three, namely, Resemblance, Contiguity and Causation; which are the only bonds that unite our thoughts together, and beget that regular train of reflection or discourse, which, in a greater or less degree, takes place among all mankind.

Point 41 from "Enquiry concerning human understanding".
Does Hume suggest that the math ideas are connected in the same way?
I guess he doesn't, but I can't find any moment in the text where he would say that those "principles of connection" are applied only to "moral" reasoning. I'll explain the word "moral" in the following paragraph.
He previously had distinguished between the "moral" reasoning (it's about facts of the nature) and the demonstrative one (it's about math).
I would also ask you to attach some excerpts to your answers.

Frege summarized Hume and mathematics as Hume's principle: quotes from Part III of Book I of David Hume's A Treatise of Human Nature (1740)... Algebra and arithmetic [are] the only sciences in which we can carry on a chain of reasoning to any degree of intricacy... preserve a perfect exactness... according as they correspond or not to that standard, we determine their relations, without any possibility of error... So there's difference for Hume about moral reasoning and arithmetic reasoning, though that later is incomplete too per Godel...


Does Hume suggest that the math ideas are connected in the same way [wrt particular ideas]?

No; see Treatise, Bk.I, Part III where Hume helds the view that mathematical propositions assert relations between ideas which "depend entirely on the ideas, which we compare together".
Relations between ides alone "can be the objects of knowledge and certainty". They are four: resemblance, contrariety, degrees in quality, and proportions in quantity or number.
They differ from the three relations of [numerical] identity, space and time, and causation, which "may be chang'd without any change in the ideas".
Relations of the former sort may be labelled necessary, those of the latter contingent.
The first three necessary relations "are discoverable at first sight, and fall more properly under the province of intuition than demonstration". Generally, "we must settle the proportions with some liberty, or proceed in a more artificial manner", i.e. we must employ mathematics [to discover proportions], which comprises geometry, arithmetic and algebra.
See R.F. Atkinson, Hume on Mathematics (The Philosophical Quarterly, 1960) and see Treatise of Human Nature (1739), Book 1: Of the understanding. Part 3 Sect.1:

There are seven different kinds of philosophical relation, viz. resemblance, identity, relations of time and place, proportion in quantity or number, degrees in any quality, contrariety, and causation. These relations may be divided into two classes; into such as depend entirely on the ideas, which we compare together, and such as may be chang'd without any change in the ideas. 'Tis from the idea of a triangle, that we discover the relation of equality, which its three angles bear to two right ones; and this relation is invariable, as long as our idea remains the same.

